# (PHP) How to obtain the filename (or file path) when a script is executed as a cron job?

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script that executes perfectly when called via the browser. It fails, however, when called as a cron job. The failure is because the script needs to access its own filename, which I do via `$thefilepath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Unfortunately, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable isn't populated when the file is called as a cron job. (I've similarly failed with trying `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`).

In case anyone is interested, the script needs to access its own filename because the filename contains an integer (for example, `filename = myfile4.php`) that is used in the calculation of a subset of rows in a database table. More specifically, `myfile4.php` takes rows with IDs from, say, 40-49, whereas `myfile5.php` takes rows with IDs from 50-59, etc.

So, my question is, given that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` fail to provide the filename (or filepath) for use in a cron job, can anyone please suggest an alternative method of accessing a script's own filename within this cron execution context?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: I've now tested both Marc B's solution (to use $argv[0]) and Martin B's solution (to use __FILE__) -- both of which worked great (thank you!). I'm not qualified to assess any nuances or other considerations of such solutions -- just very glad to have gotten one that works.

Answer (score 0):

`$argv[0]` will always contain the name of the script: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: That should not be used. Imagine a script acting as a front controller which takes the cronjob name (which would be the interesting part) as a parameter; or a defined alias for the php-file.

Comment: I've now tested both Marc B's solution (to use $argv[0]) and Martin B's solution (to use __FILE__) -- both of which worked great (thank you!). I'm not qualified to assess any nuances or other considerations of such solutions -- just very glad to have gotten one that works.